# How to use google maps in cordova Ionic windows phone app

Tags: javascript, cordova, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework

I'm facing a rather annoying problem in my cordova/ionic app for windows phone.
As all external scripts are blocked by the windows phone cordova platform, I cannot include and use the google maps js api.
I read up on some issues here and googled the problem, and found out that you can include external scripts within an iframe and use it form here. Did that, works fine.
However, I would like to use the google maps api from my parent frame. I tried passing the google variable from the iframe to the top frame by assigning:

```
parent.google = google
```

This gives me an access denied error due to cross domain security mumbo jumbo in IE. Then i tried assigning document.domain to something that is the same for both parent and child frame, but this produces a JS error. 
I'm not able to use postMessage as methods on the google will not be stringify'ed.

My question is: is there a way to pass google to my top frame as an object in IE?

Comment: *cross domain security mumbo jumbo*

Comment: if external scripts are blocked, look into the whitelist plugin, the problem might be there

Comment: the whitelist plugin does not support windows phone. I've also tried adding this to my config.xml:   <access origin="*"/>
  <access origin="https://maps.gstatic.com/*" />
  <access origin="https://*.googleapis.com/*" />

Comment: have you resolved this ?

Comment: sadly, no. I switched over to leaflet instead, as I can include that script locally. As the google maps script is basically scripts that includes other scritps, it violates the security policies of the windows phone platform.