# cordova Ionic use google maps on windows phone

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, windows-phone

I built a Cordova Application with ionic framework and need to display a map with directions and do reverse geocoding. Everything works fine on Android and iOS. Just on Windows Phone I get the following error:
Can't load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps.api/js..... An app can't load remote web content in the local context.
Plus the error "google is undefined".

I added the following lines in the index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://maps.gstatic.com/ https://mts0.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="lib/js/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
```

I searched all over google but didn't find an answer that helped. Adding the whitlist plugin didn't change anything.

On this link: [How to use google maps in cordova Ionic windows phone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251784/how-to-use-google-maps-in-cordova-ionic-windows-phone-app) they talk about the option to include external scripts within an iframe and use it form here, but I don't know how.

I hope somebody can help me out with my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check this link https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/implement-google-maps-using-ionicframework/

Comment: This is what I already have in my Application. It does work on Android and iOS but not on Windows Phone.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: sadly I still haven't found a solution.

Comment: Still no luck on a solution?

Comment: I got the same issue, map is working fine for Android and IOS.

In case of windows it says "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'google' is undefined"

I work around this to find the rootcause but no luck, for me it seems issue of windows + ionic because I found working example at https://github.com/dotnetcurry/wp8-cordova-googlemap for windows without ionic.